# Entity Framework Core migrations using dockerized postgresql image. No such host is known exception

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, ef-core-2.2

In my aspnet.core project I would like to use my dockerized postgresql image.
Container is running correctly. (I am using Windows but server running on ubuntu18.04 server)

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
    a01980eb90bc        postgres:11.4       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   pg
```

appsettings.json file looks like

```
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "LibvirtConnection": "User ID =postgres;Password=*****;Server=185.22.98.7:5432;Port=5432;Database=libvirt;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
      },
```

Startup class looks like

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
                services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt =>
                    opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibvirtConnection")));
            }
```

I got exception when I try run dotnet ef database update

```
    dotnet ef database update
    info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
          Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'AppDbContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL' with options: None
    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known
       at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
       at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 663
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 555
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 414
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 273
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 153
       at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists() in C:\projects\npgsql-entityframeworkcore-postgresql\src\EFCore.PG\S   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists() in C:\projects\npgsql-entityframeworkcore-postgresql\src\EFCore.PG\Storage\Internal\NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.cs:line 190
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
    No such host is known
```

Comment: Is your ASP.net application also dockerized?

Comment: No it is not dockerized

Comment: Can you ping the server (185.22.98.7 I assume) from the machine running the ASP.net app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason was I combined my server and port together

Before:
`Server=185.22.98.7:5432;Port=5432`

After:
`Server=185.22.98.7;Port=5432`

Answer (score 0):

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known

**Double check your connection string for typo's!!!** *Copy/paste the info!*

I'm not sure about the OP's connection string, according to the documentation it's in this format:

```
Host=dbServerName.random.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=5432;Database=postgres;Username=admin;Password=NotRealPassword
```

**REF:**
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

[image]